# Build Pascal with Sublime Text 3

Tags: build-automation, freepascal, sublimetext3

I want to build Free Pascal with Sublime Text 3. I always get an encoding error (see below). I also tried to save the file with encoding.

I created a `sublime-build` file:

```
{
    "cmd":["fpc $file & ${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "shell" : true,
}
```

My test program is a simple hello world:

```
Program HelloWorld;
begin
  writeln("Hello, world!");
  readln;
end.
```

My Error-Code:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['fpc C:\\Users\\korndi\\Documents\\FREI\\hellop.p & C:\\Users\\korndi\\Documents\\FREI/hellop.exe']]
[dir: C:\Users\korndi\Documents\FREI]
[path: C:\Python33\;;C:\FPC\2.6.2\bin\i386-Win32]
```

Comment: 1) The pascal is strange with double quotes.  Maybe sublime detects that -A functions are used for output by FPC, and thus assumes output is ascii.  But output utf-8 in a console on Windows is not normal. Probably have to tweak sublime somehow for that. In general: just use Lazarus :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will build your file
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will run it (in external cmd!!, *Aww yiss!*)

```
{
    "cmd": ["fpc", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
    "selector": "source.pascal",
    "variants": [
        {
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/c", "$file_base_name.exe & pause"],
            "name": "Run",
            "shell": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please help with an error? When I press ctrl shift b, I get "'program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." But when I run it manually (by opening .exe file) it runs just fine.

Comment: @D.N Are you pointing to the exe file? You first need to build it (create the executable), then you can run it from sublime. What it does is that it executes a command `start cmd /c your_file.exe & pause` in a commandline/shell. It needs to see the file. It is an error message from cmd, right? What directory does it work in?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but today it seems to work normally, yesterday I had to add directory with exe file to Path. Today, however, it doesn't matter where the file is. Thank you though :)

Answer (score 1):

I've made a build system based on Qwerty's one. When you press Ctrl-B it automatically compiles AND runs your program. Also you have 2 old vars. Basic Pascal one os renamed to *Pascal - Compile*

```
{
        "shell": true,
        "cmd": ["fpc", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/c", "$file_base_name.exe", "&", "pause"],
        "selector": "source.pascal",
        "variants": [
            {
                "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/c", "$file_base_name.exe & pause"],
                "name": "Run",
                "shell": true
            },
            {
                "cmd": ["fpc", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
                "name": "Compile",
                "shell": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont need to enter data while program execution you can try this one:

```
{
    "cmd": ["fpc", "${file_name}", "&&", "${file_base_name}", "&&", "echo."],
    "shell": true
}
```

`echo.` prints a new line.